# How to have difference between two dates PHP

Tags: php, date, mktime

I have a switch case with different dates.

```
        switch($date){
        case 'lastweek':
            $this->setdate(date('Y-m-d',mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 7, 2014)));
            $this->get();
            break;
        case 'thisweek':
        $now = new DateTime('2010-11-17');
        $after = new DateTime('2010-11-21');
        $interval = $after->diff($now);

            $this->setdate($interval);**
            $this->get();
            break;
        case 'nextweek':
            $this->setdate(date('Y-m-d',mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 21, 2014)));
            $this->get();
            break;
    }
```

With that, I have pictures who are coming according the the date. By the way, when the date is "this week" I want the picture staying until the next date ("nextweek").
I tried something as you can see with the $interval but it doesn't work.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: Use [datetime object](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php),  and you can do something like `$date = new DateTime('next week');`

Comment: You need to use `DateTime`, not a string generated by the `date` function.

Comment: `date()` returns  a date/time string. It is **NOT** an object, and `$after->diff()` will just give you "attempting to call method of non-object" errors. You want the DateTime class.

Comment: @sjagr: ah yeah, right. mondays... Fixed. but the rest of the point still applies. string/int->method() won't work.

Comment: @MarcB Agreed, cheers!

Comment: You must have a different concept of a week than I do. I always thought a week was 7 days.  :)

Comment: Mike Brant we just don't care about how many days there are exactly I will change it, its just the way to do. I updated my code by the way :) But I have "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"